# How to select all columns with sum function

Tags: sql

Assuming there is a table with 100 columns, how can I select all columns with a sum without having to type out all the columns?

For example something like this:

```
select *, sum(price) as sales
from table
group by *
order by date
```

Comment: You can't. Some ORMs have extra functionlity on top of SQL to implement "column selectors" but SQL doesn't offer any help here.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, doing `group by pk_column` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select table.* , t.sales from table
inner join (select id, sum(price) as sales from table group by id ) t
on table.id=t.id
order by date
```

But in general it is not recommended to use an stare in a select statement,
for example dont use * in table-valued function